# Exact definitions of loss functions in sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I know that I may change loss function to one of the following:

> loss : str, 'hinge' or 'log' or 'modified_huber'
>      The loss function to be used. Defaults to 'hinge'. The hinge loss is
>      a margin loss used by standard linear SVM models. The 'log' loss is
>      the loss of logistic regression models and can be used for
>      probability estimation in binary classifiers. 'modified_huber'
>      is another smooth loss that brings tolerance to outliers.

But what the definitions of this functions?
I understand that `hinge` is `max(0, 1 - margin)`. And what are others too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sklearn's source code is available on GitHub, so you can examine it. List of loss functions can be found in [sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/096070d1059c780478bb704049b87c8a17826c0a/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L276).  Definitions of that losses are here: [sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L46](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/096070d1059c780478bb704049b87c8a17826c0a/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L46)

Answer (score 4):

Here are the graphs of all these functions, taken from the [scikit-learn example gallery](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_loss_functions.html):

[image]

In the current [dev version of the example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_loss_functions.html), the losses are implemented inline in the script.